# How to pause a css animation, and then continue running from the pause point?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations

I'm playing a CSS animation with infinite iterations, until some point I pausing it from java script (using technique from [here](http://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/)).

At later time I resume the animation. The problem is that the animation is restarting from the beginning point, and not from the last point before the pause.

Does there is a way to continue the animation from the pause point, without jumping to the start?

Edit: Between the pause and resume I also change the `animation duration`, see the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tJAWw/).
You should see some 'jumping'. Need explanation about this strange behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I've just started to dig into JS myself, so there are surely better ways to do this, but how about something like this - [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GLRMF/1/) (Unprefixed version).

CSS

```
#box {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #393939;
    animation: move 2s linear infinite;
    animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes move {
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

JS:

```
(function () {

    var box = document.getElementById('box');

    box.onclick = function () {

        if (box.style.animationPlayState === "paused") {
            box.style.animationPlayState = "running";

        } else {
            box.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
        }

    };
})();
```

Based on if the animation is running or paused I change the `animation-play-state` onclick.

***EDIT: Added the css code.***

Comment: Had a quick look, and can't really explain the "jumping", but I'll look into it and see if I can come up with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/zhang6464/MSqMQ/

Just switch `animation-play-state` css property to be `paused`, according to the article you supplied(http://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/